# Pytorch: define custom function

Tags: python, pytorch

I wanted to write my own activation function, but I got a problem. Saying the matrix multiplication will call `.data`. I searched but got little useful information. Any help will be appreciated. The error information is

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "defineAutogradFuncion.py", line 126, in <module>
        test = gradcheck(argmin, input, eps=1e-6, atol=1e-4)
      File "/home/zhaosl/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/torch/autograd/gradcheck.py", line 154, in gradcheck
        output = func(*inputs)
      File "defineAutogradFuncion.py", line 86, in forward
        output = output.mm(dismap).squeeze(-1)
      File "/home/zhaosl/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/torch/autograd/variable.py", line 578, in mm
        output = Variable(self.data.new(self.data.size(0), matrix.data.size(1)))
      File "/home/zhaosl/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/torch/tensor.py", line 374, in data
        raise RuntimeError('cannot call .data on a torch.Tensor: did you intend to use autograd.Variable?')
    RuntimeError: cannot call .data on a torch.Tensor: did you intend to use autograd.Variable?
```

```py
    class Softargmin(torch.autograd.Function):
    """
    We can implement our own custom autograd Functions by subclassing
    torch.autograd.Function and implementing the forward and backward passes
    which operate on Tensors.
    """
    @staticmethod
    def forward(self, input):
        """
        In the forward pass we receive a Tensor containing the input and return a
        Tensor containing the output. You can cache arbitrary Tensors for use in the
        backward pass using the save_for_backward method.
        """
        #P = Fun.softmax(-input)
        inputSqueeze = input.squeeze(-1)
        P = Fun.softmax(-inputSqueeze)
        self.save_for_backward(P)

        output = P.permute(0,2,3,1)
        dismap = torch.arange(0,output.size(-1)+1).unsqueeze(1)
        output = output.mm(dismap).squeeze(-1)
       return output
    @staticmethod
    def backward(self, grad_output):
        """
        In the backward pass we receive a Tensor containing the gradient of the loss
        with respect to the output, and we need to compute the gradient of the loss
        with respect to the input.
        """
        P, = self.saved_tensors
        P = P.unsqueeze(-1)
        Pk = torch.squeeze(P,-1).permute(0,2,3,1)
        k = torch.arange(0,Pk.size(-1)+1).unsqueeze(1)
        sumkPk = Pk.mm(k)
        sumkPk = sumkPk.unsqueeze(1).expand(P.size())
        i = torch.arange(0,Pk.size(-1)+1).view(1,-1,1,1,1).expand(P.size())
        grad_output_expand =grad_output.unsqueeze(-1).unsqueeze(1).expand(P.size())
        grad_input = grad_output_expand*P*(sumkPk-i)
        return grad_input
```

Comment: Please provide your complete source code...

Comment: Why would you want to implement your own backward function. PyTorch has builtin autograd. As long as your operations are differentiable, you do not need to write a custom backward function.

Answer (score 4):

The most basic element in PyTorch is a `Tensor`, which is the equivalent of `numpy.ndarray` with the only difference being that a `Tensor` can be put onto a GPU for any computation.

A `Variable` is a wrapper around `Tensor` that contains three attributes: `data`, `grad` and `grad_fn`. `data` contains the original `Tensor`; `grad` contains the derivative/gradient of some value with respect to this `Variable`; and `grad_fn` is a pointer to the `Function` object that created this `Variable`. The `grad_fn` attribute is actually the key for `autograd` to work properly since PyTorch uses those pointers to build the computation graph at each iteration and carry out the differentiations for all `Variables` in your graph accordingly. This is not only about differentiating correctly through this custom `Function` object you are creating.

[image]

Hence whenever you create some `Tensor` in your computation that requires differentiation, wrap it as a `Variable`. First, this would enable the `Tensor` to be able to save the resulting derivative/gradient value after you call `backward()`. Second, this helps `autograd` build a correct computation graph.

Another thing to notice is that whenever you send a `Variable` into your computation graph, any value that is computed using this `Variable` will automatically be a `Variable`. So you don't have to manually wrap all `Tensors` in your computation graph.

You might want to take a look at [this](http://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/autograd_tutorial.html).

Going back to your error, it's a little difficult to figure out what is really causing the trouble because you are not showing all of your code (information like how you are using this custom `Function` in your computation graph), but I suspect that what most likely has happened is that you used this `Function` in a subgraph that required to be differentiated through, when PyTorch used numerical gradient check on your model to see if the differentiation is correct, it assumed that every node in that subgraph was a `Variable` because that is necessary for differentiation through that subgraph to happen, then it tried to call the `data` attribute of that `Variable`, most likely because that value is used somewhere in the differentiation, and failed because that node was in fact a `Tensor` and did not have a `data` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The pytorch tensors you are using should be wrapped into a `torch.Variable` object like so

```
v=torch.Variable(mytensor)
```

The autograd assumes that tensors are wrapped in Variables and then can access the data using `v.data`. The `Variable` class is the data structure Autograd uses to perform numerical derivatives during the backward pass. Make sure the data tensors you pass are wrapped in `torch.Variable`.

-Mo

Comment: Thanks! And I am still confused, Does the tensors used in forward and backward have to be Variables? Autograd use the Variable to backward pass, but I write the backward myself, so It seems like no need to use Variable, or I needn't to write the backward, because Autograd can do it self with Variable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of simple activation that uses torch activation functions inside but works and can be extended to custom.

```py
import torch as pt
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.nn.modules import Module

# custom activation 
class Act(Module):
    def forward(self, z):
        if(do_ratio > 0):
            return nn.functional.dropout(pt.tanh(z), do_ratio)
        else:
            return pt.tanh(z)

act_fn = Act()
model = pt.nn.Sequential(
        pt.nn.Linear(features, n_layer0, bias=enable_bias),
        act_fn,
        pt.nn.Linear(n_layer0, n_layer1, bias=enable_bias),
        act_fn,
        pt.nn.Linear(n_layer1, n_layer2, bias=enable_bias)        
)
```