# Pytorch custom activation functions?

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, pytorch, activation-function

I'm having issues with implementing custom activation functions in Pytorch, such as Swish. How should I go about implementing and using custom activation functions in Pytorch?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There are **four** possibilities depending on what you are looking for. You will need to ask yourself two questions:

**Q1)** Will your activation function have learnable parameters?

If **yes**, you have no choice but to create your activation function as an `nn.Module` class because you need to store those weights.

If **no**, you are free to simply create a normal function, or a class, depending on what is convenient for you.

**Q2)** Can your activation function be expressed as a combination of existing PyTorch functions?

If **yes**, you can simply write it as a combination of existing PyTorch function and won't need to create a `backward` function which defines the gradient.

If **no** you will need to write the gradient by hand.

**Example 1: SiLU function**

The [SiLU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier_(neural_networks)#:%7E:text=of%20this%20article.-,SiLU,-%5Bedit%5D) function `f(x) = x * sigmoid(x)` does not have any learned weights and can be written entirely with existing PyTorch functions, thus you can simply define it as a function:

```
def silu(x):
    return x * torch.sigmoid(x)
```

and then simply use it as you would have `torch.relu` or any other activation function.

**Example 2: SiLU with learned slope**

In this case you have one learned parameter, the slope, thus you need to make a class of it.

```
class LearnedSiLU(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, slope = 1):
        super().__init__()
        self.slope = slope * torch.nn.Parameter(torch.ones(1))

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.slope * x * torch.sigmoid(x)
```

**Example 3: with backward**

If you have something for which you need to create your own gradient function, you can look at this example: [Pytorch: define custom function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46509039/pytorch-define-custom-function)

Comment: Did you mean: "...If yes, you have no choice ***BUT*** to create your activation function as an nn.Module class because you need to store those weights."

Comment: yes that is what i meant

Answer (score 2):

You can write a customized activation function like below (e.g. weighted Tanh).

```
class weightedTanh(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, weights = 1):
        super().__init__()
        self.weights = weights

    def forward(self, input):
        ex = torch.exp(2*self.weights*input)
        return (ex-1)/(ex+1)
```

Don’t bother about backpropagation if you use `autograd` compatible operations.

Comment: Thanks, but it gives me a _-main__.Swish is not a Module subclass error.

Comment: @ZeroMaxinumXZ please share your code by updating your question.

Comment: Issue has been solved over on https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/custom-activation-functions/43055

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the following `SinActivation` sub-class of `nn.Module` to implement the `sin` activation function.

```
class SinActivation(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SinActivation, self).__init__()
        return
    def forward(self, x):
        return torch.sin(x)
```