# How to initialize parameters of an activation function?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, neural-network, activation-function

I'm studying the basics of neural networks with pytorch, and I'm having a hard time understanding how the activation function should work.

I don't understand what shape should the trainable parameters of my activation function have.
Should they have the same shape of the input dataset? Or should they have the shape of a single element in the dataset?

From what I understood the activation function should take as input the whole dataset, but I'm unsure of how to initialize the parameters.

```
class customModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, units):
        super(customModel, self).__init__()
        self.p1 = nn.parameter.Parameter(torch.ones(units))
        self.p2 = nn.parameter.Parameter(torch.ones(units))
        self.b1 = nn.parameter.Parameter(torch.zeros(units))
        self.b2 = nn.parameter.Parameter(torch.zeros(units))
    def forward(self, inputs):
        out = myCustomActivationFunction(inputs, self.p1, self.p2, self.b1, self.b2)
        return out
```

Comment: In general, you wouldn't train an activation function. Typically they're just there to add nonlinearity between linear layers, and you train the linear layers.

Comment: I think you are confusing network layers with activation.
Generally, the activation function you choose to use depends on your task. same as choosing you whole network architecture depends on your task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## In short

The activation was used to create a "Non-Linearity" between each layer
which is always Linear(without activation function)
and we usually choose the activation function based on our task
Such as we use ReLu Between the neural network layers to create a "Non-Linearity" between each layer
and we use sigmoid in the output layer to normalize value between 0-1
for the binary classification task using 0.5 as a threshold for classify between two classes

## Long

To Fully Grasp how activation function was used in Neural Network
**First of all**, we need to create a clear understanding
In Neural Networks between

- Neuron & layers
- Trainable Parameters of The Network (Weight & Bias)
- Activation Function

To Understand the Neural Network I recommend you to understand the Linear Regression model first! since it will be easier to understand about weight

y = mx+b is a Linear Function that can be leveraged to create a simple model
that can predict data with Linear correlation (we call this model Linear Regression)

with "x" as the input "y" as the output and "m,b" as the features

this "m" and "b" is a trainable parameters while x is an input features

[More Explanation About Linear Regression](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nk2CQITm_eo)

**It's a bit hard to explain since I can't attach the image at my reputation Level So I'll attach the video link instead

**Assume you are already familiar with Linear Regression**

The Neural Networks are like a chain of Linear Models connected
which will be called **Neuron**, Stacking as a Layer

Layers1 Example (First Layer Generally Called Input layer)

because it's the layer that we'll put ours features in

[x1]

[x2]

[x3]

each neuron in the layer will have a "LINE" that connected to every neuron in the next layer

each "LINE" contain its own w (weight) which is a trainable parameter

the same as "m" and "b" we can train in y = mx+b

when computing, the input was put in each X of the input layer

and then they will times the weight on the LINE connecting to each neuron of the next layer and sum them up at the destination

the formula is

Yi= sum(Xi*Wi)

**To Simplify**
In the image below

You can think of it as computing 2 Linear Regression models Separately

then sum the output up -> use it as the input for the next Linear Regression model which predicts the gender

**IT IS AT THIS PART** where we'll really need the activation function
Assume that the previous layers provide the information on how to predict the
***BIOLOGICAL*** Gender, Given Height & Weight

The possibility of the output layer which is just

y = mx+b formular

is -infinity & +infinity

how would you classify this output into two classes?

The Answer is by using an activation function such as [Sigmoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function)
which normalizes any range of value into between 0-1 range
thinking of this as a percentage we can now use a 0.5 cutoff threshold
to classify below 0.5 into class "0" and over 0.5 into class "1"

[Simple Neural Network Image](https://victorzhou.com/media/neural-network-post/network3.png)

## Summary

As you can see, We don't train the activation function
it's the trainable parameters that will be trained!
The activation was used to create a "Non-Linearity" between each layer
we usually choose the activation function based on our task
Such as Sigmoid For Classification

To Implement Custom Activation, Just Create a Function that receives 1 input and then returns something

```py
def custom_act(x):
  return -x
```

in case you need it to be trainable (which usually doesn't need to)

Referring to this Question, Already Have Good Explanation
[Pytorch custom activation functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55765234/pytorch-custom-activation-functions)

### Additional Information

[What Is Neural Network](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aircAruvnKk)

[Using Sigmoid for Logistic Regression](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yIYKR4sgzI8)

[Activation Function Explain For Binary Classification and Keras Implementation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m0pIlLfpXWE)