# Can Pytorch handle custom nonlinear activation functions that are not 1-to-1 functions?

Tags: pytorch, neural-network, activation-function

I am interested in making a neural network with custom nonlinear activation functions that are not 1-to-1 functions.

I see that it is possible to add [custom nonlinear activation functions to Pytorch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55765234/pytorch-custom-activation-functions), but the only functions that are considered are 1-to-1 functions. That is, there is a linear layer which performs a dot product, and then it is fed to a nonlinear function, which takes a single input and returns and output,

[image]

Is it possible to have a custom nonlinear activation function that depends on multiple input arguments of the previous layer?

So instead of taking a single number, the output depends on all of the inputs of the input layer. In general it would be a function of the inputs and tunable weights f(x, A) that cannot be expressed as  f(x dot A). One such function for example might look like:

[image]

Is it possible to use such a complex activation layer in a NN in pytorch?
Or is this too unconventional?

Answer (score 1):

You can write absolutely any logic in pytorch module, no need to be limited to dot products or pointwise nonlinearities

```
class CustomLayer(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, size_in):
        super().__init__()
        self.A = nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor(size_in, size_in))

    def forward(self, x):
        # x is a matrix batch x hidden_size
        # just write any logic you wish here using self.A
        return ...
```

Comment: And can it automatically do back-propagation training?

Comment: Yes, as long as these are differentiable operations etc. there are  various limitations you will encounter when you stretch it, mostly having to do with the need of vectorization and shape determinism. But overall yes, All modern ML frameworks implement automatic differentiation